# Releasing memory of a node in shared memory using boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I have created a shared memory which has a list into it. I need to continuosly add nodes into the list.
My another application reads the list and pops the read content. 
The problem i am facing is the node popped doesnt releases the memory so while the first application keeps on inserting at a point it throws segmentation fault. Please guide me as how to release the node so that that space can be utilised by my first application to allocate new node.

Snippet of my code is

```
#include </tcs/dev/lib/boost_1_38_0/boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include </tcs/dev/lib/boost_1_38_0/boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include </tcs/dev/lib/boost_1_38_0/boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include </tcs/dev/lib/boost_1_38_0/boost/multi_index_container.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace multi_index;

class marketdata
{
  public:
    int x;
    float y;
};


int main ()
{
    marketdata m[0];
    m[0].x=1;
    m[0].y=1;
    // boost::interprocess::list iterator itr;

    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    try{
      managed_shared_memory segment
         (open_only
         ,"MySharedMemory"); //segment name
      typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<marketdata, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
         ShmemAllocator;
      typedef boost::interprocess::list<marketdata, ShmemAllocator> MyList;
      MyList *mylist = segment.find<MyList>("MyList").first;
boost::interprocess::list<marketdata, ShmemAllocator> :: iterator itr;
           for(itr=mylist->begin(); itr != mylist->end(); ++itr)
                { cout << (*itr).x << " ";
                 cout << endl;
                 mylist->pop_front();
                 //multi_index::multi_index_container::delete_node_(itr);
                 sleep(1);
                }

      segment.destroy<MyList>("MyList");
   }
   catch(...){
      shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
      throw;
   }
   shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why absolute paths in your include? That's going to make upgrading to later versions really suck!

Comment: Thanks Billy for your suggestion. It was just for some testing purpose so have added absolute paths. Would definitely change that

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a mutex lock. You can't just add and delete memory in threaded/interprocess applications with taking account that one thread/process may be trying to access memory while another is currently using it.

Comment: I have tried push_back statement in my 2nd application also. It worked so i guess there is no need of mutex as in our case write to list is much more faster that read. Can we delete a particular node from shared memory?

Comment: I'd still highly recommend a lock. Sometimes it can funny about working or not, you could just luck up and have it not reading and writing at the same time. If not, your program is going to crash and burn. Anyway, I believe there is a deallocate method somewhere or another.

Comment: Thanks we would try that but lock is not preferrable in our requirement as both applications need simultaneous access, first to write and second to read. Is there any other way out?